# Постоянный GET-запрос (Таймер или Сокет)

Tags: objective-c, ios, iphone, ios7

Уважаемые, укажите на правильный путь и пример. Есть сайт, на который посылается ПОСТ-запрос - сообщение оператору. Узнать ответ от оператора - послать ГЕТ-запрос и получить джейсон.

И тут я засел на принятии решения, то ли использовать таймер и опрашивать сайт на наличие ответа, то ли юзать сокеты. Т.е. мне нужен постоянный слушатель сайта, пока не закончится разговор между оператором и юзером.

- Ничего толкового не могу найти по сокетам с использованием ПОСТ-ГЕТ.
- Я так понимаю, что сокет должен слушать сайт/порт, пока я его сам не закрою, правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да лучше использовать WebSocket https://github.com/square/SocketRocket , я юзаю https://github.com/briancollins/UnittWebSocketClient тоже норм. Но для их работы на стороне сервера должен быть SocketServer, а не тупо сайт.
Если сайт Вам не принадлежит, то легче сделать пулинг через таймер, как Вы и пишете.
По стандрату сокет схема выглядит так: wss://site.ru (SSL) или простой ws://site.ru

Comment: да, сайт чужой. прийдется делать через таймер. Спасибо.